# What is the role of const in function argument and why we take address of vector in comparison function?

Tags: c++, function, vector, compare

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool compare(const vector<long long int>&v1,const vector<long long int>&v2 ) { 
 return v1[0] < v2[0]; 
}
```

Can anyone tell me the use of const keyword and & in the function argument ?

Comment: `&` take the parameter by reference; `const` not able to change the parameter.  Can I refer you to the book list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282

Comment: This is not the address. Its pass by reference which is a very important c++ concept that should be taught very early in your c++ book.

Comment: What will happen if we don't use both & and const ?

Comment: no `&` - pass by value - take a copy of the vector and all of it's elements; no `const` - you can make changes to the parameter (vector) in the function but the caller will not see your changes as the function is working on a copy

Comment: const means inside the function you will not modify the vector.

Comment: @drescherjm here we are not modifying our vector we are just changing the order so what's the need of const ?

Comment: Inside the compare you are not modifying the vector at all. You are just comparing the first element of 2 vectors

Comment: @AdityaAggarwal _"...changing the order..."_ nope not happening, no order changing going on in the posted code just a comparison

Comment: Yes sorry , we are just comparing so what's the need of const ?

Comment: To reassure the caller that a comparison function will not change their vector. And to stop the implementer of the comparison function making a silly mistake.

Comment: Some of the answers in this question answer why const is used: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967177/when-to-use-const-and-const-reference-in-function-args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967177/when-to-use-const-and-const-reference-in-function-args)