# Why few people type const-correct code? Will const-correct code compile better/faster?

Tags: c++, c, const-correctness

I **very** often pass pointer as functions args for read-only args (e.g. structs and such). For instance in this constructor:

```
Chunk::Chunk(const string& text, COLOR * background, COLOR * foreground);
```

I use to prefer this way (not const-correct) because I thought it was easier to read. 
However, I am starting to feel this is dirty and do instead:

```
Chunk::Chunk(const string& text, const COLOR * const background, 
                          const COLOR * const foreground);
```

It may seem harder to understand at first, but only until you get use to it. My question:

Why no one does it right? (I've seen little code like this) 
It is better/smaller/faster compiled?

I **do** know what's the difference, but I really dont care the different semantic because anyone reading the code can see the args are read-only. (who would change a pointer address?)

I **do** know I could use references instead, but let's suppose I dont want to (or I am in plain C).

Comment: maybe you should write `const string& text` unless you need a copy

Comment: I disagree. The majority of people I work with are very rigorous on the cost correctness of our code.

Comment: I don't think, it's really a technical question, why somebody writes a bad code

Comment: The two `const` modifiers do different things; the first restricts the function from modifying the object, while the second restricts the function from modifying its own parameter within its body.

Comment: Const-correct code will not compile *significantly* better/faster than non-const-correct code. Many people fail to write const-correct code because they are lazy, sloppy, overconfident code-monkeys. That said, it is possible to go too far and use "const" where it isn't really helpful.

Comment: This question is genuine. Voting for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you've listed

```
Chunk::Chunk(string text, const COLOR * const background, 
                          const COLOR * const foreground);
```

You should probably also pass the string by `const&` unless you intentionally want a local copy of that string. Also, in my opinion, the color parameter should just be declared as `const COLOR *` instead of `const COLOR * const`. The second `const` just indicates that the function will not re-point the `background` and `foreground` pointers to some other chunks of memory locally. It does not affect the caller, and so it is an implementation detail. So, even if the implementation file explicitly lists them as `const COLOR * const` the prototype in the header should read

```
Chunk::Chunk(string text, const COLOR *background, 
                          const COLOR *foreground);
```

Comment: +1, Also, on the second `const`: The standard states that in a *function declaration*, the const-ness of the parameter type is removed from the signature (where the parameter type in this case is `COLOR const *`). It is different in the *function definition*, where it tells the compiler that it should check for assignments internally.

Answer (score 1):

const keyword is for human being and it is incredibly powerful.

Have a look at this http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm for more information on const optimization.

Answer (score 0):

const correctness helps compiler to generate faster code. For example, if you are passing a non-const pointer to a function compiler may assume that that function has modified the memory block that has referenced.

EDIT: (from Exceptional C++ Style 40 New Engineering Puzzles, Programming Problems, and Solutions)

**Does declaring the parameter and/or the return value as const help the compiler generate more optimal code or otherwise improve its code generation?**

In short, no, it probably doesn't.

**Why or why not?**

What could the compiler do better? Could it avoid a copy of the parameter or the return value? No, because the parameter is already passed by reference, and the return is already by reference. Could it put a copy of x or someY into read-only memory? No, because both x and someY live outside its scope and come from and/or are given to the outside world. Even if someY is dynamically allocated on the fly within f itself, it and its ownership are given up to the caller.

But what about possible optimizations of code that appears inside the body of f? Because of the const, could the compiler somehow improve the code it generates for the body of f?

Just because x and someY are declared const doesn't necessarily mean that their bits are physically const. Why not? Because either class might have mutable members or their moral equivalent, namely const_casts inside member functions. Indeed, the code inside f itself might perform const_casts or C-style casts that turn the const declarations into lies.

There is one case where saying const can really mean something, and that is when objects are made const at the point where they are defined. In that case, the compiler can often successfully put such "really const" objects into read-only memory, especially if they are PODs whose memory images can be created at compile time and therefore can be stored right inside the program's executable image itself. Such objects are colloquially called "ROM-able."

*It's a common belief that const correctness helps compilers generate tighter code. Yes, const is indeed a Good Thing, but the point of this Item is that const is mainly for humans, rather than for compilers and optimizers.*

Comment: Not really true. Const correct code makes for easier to maintain code as it documents intent.

Comment: There's really not much of a performance benefit to using `const`.  See also [Constants and compiler optimization in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212237/constants-and-compiler-optimization-in-c)

Comment: from wikipedia: three advantages: ... The compiler may be able to perform code optimizations knowing that the value of the object will not change once created.

Comment: @cprogrammer only if you perform a global optimization (occur very rarely because it is expensive). See gotw item 81.

Comment: The wikipedia article is misleading though.  For example, for a variable that is not passed-by-reference to another function, the compiler already knows if you're modifying it or not.  For optimizations, const is important for global's (or other static members), but for parameters, the compiler already aware of what is being done with the variable.

Comment: -1: This is a common misconception. "const" declarations of pointers or references cannot help the optimizer because that says nothing about the constness of the objects being referenced or pointed-to (it's a property of the pointer/reference). The object referenced or pointed to by a const pointer/reference can indeed legally mutate (for example because of aliasing) and so the optimizer can make no special assumption about it.

Comment: gotw:81 => http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm

Comment: @Alessandro and if the compiler is doing global optimization it doesn't need the const keyword as it knows globally if it changes or not

Comment: Would not const correctness also allow the intelligent use of overloaded methods which make defensive copies of their return values when necessary, and do not make defensive copies when not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main feature of const is compile-time correctness checking, performance increase is more like a pleasant side effect.

Comment: Except that there's no such an effect. The optimizer doesn't even "see" the const-ness of references or pointers, it's simply something that has no semantic meaning at all at that level. Const correctness has been designed as an help for PROGRAMMERS, not compilers... it's IMO questionable also if it's an help for programmers, but that's another story.