# Technique for factoring find like methods?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, constants, const-iterator

I am looking for a technique to factor find like methods. The problem is the following. I need a find method on a container that does not need to modify the container contents to do the search. However there should be a const and a non-const version of it since, it could lead to the modification of the container in the case an iterator is returned instead of a const_iterator.
In those two cases, the code will be exactly the same, only the accessors will be evaluated to constXXX or XXX and the compiler will do the job. Hoewer from a design and maintaining point of view it does not look smart to have those two methods implemented two times. (And I would really like to avoid using a macro for that...)
What I mean is also very well illustrated by that piece of code from the gcc implementation of the stl in stl_tree.h:

```cpp
template<typename _Key, typename _Val, typename _KeyOfValue, 
  typename _Compare, typename _Alloc>
  typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue,
          _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator
  _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::
find(const _Key& __k)
{
  iterator __j = _M_lower_bound(_M_begin(), _M_end(), __k);
  return (__j == end()
      || _M_impl._M_key_compare(__k,
                _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? end() : __j;
}

template<typename _Key, typename _Val, typename _KeyOfValue,
       typename _Compare, typename _Alloc>
typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue,
          _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator
_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::
find(const _Key& __k) const
{
  const_iterator __j = _M_lower_bound(_M_begin(), _M_end(), __k);
  return (__j == end()
      || _M_impl._M_key_compare(__k, 
                _S_key(__j._M_node))) ? end() : __j;
}
```

You can see that the prototypes of the methods are different but the code written in the implementation is actually the same.

I came up with two possible solutions:
the first one is with a const_cast and the other one is with a helper templated struct.
I have produced a simple example of those two approaches here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
  typedef int*       iterator;
  typedef const int* const_iterator;

  int m;

  Data():m(-3){}
};

struct A : public Data
{
  const_iterator find(/*const Key& k */) const
  {
    A *me = const_cast < A* > ( this );
        return const_iterator( me->find(/*k*/) );
  }

  iterator find(/*const Key& k */){
    return &m; }
};

//the second one is with the use of an internal template structure:

struct B : public Data
{

  template<class Tobj, class Titerator>
    struct Internal
   {
      Titerator find( Tobj& obj/*, const Key& k */ ){
        return &(obj.m); }
    };

  const_iterator find( /*const Key& k */ ) const
  {
    Internal<const B, const_iterator> internal;
    return internal.find( *this/*, k*/ );
  }

  iterator find( /*const Key& k */ )
  {
    Internal<B,iterator> internal;
    return internal.find( *this/*, obs*/ );
  }
};


int main()
{
  {
    A a;
    a.find();
    A::iterator it = a.find();
    cout << *it << endl;


    const A& a1(a);
    A::const_iterator cit = a1.find();
    cout << *cit << endl;
  }

  {
    B b;
    b.find();
    B::iterator it = b.find();
    cout << *it << endl;


    const B& b1(b);
    B::const_iterator cit = b1.find();
    cout << *cit << endl;
  }
}
```

It is probably a very well known problem, and I would like to know if some c++ guru comes up with a good design pattern to fix that problem. And especially I would like to know if someone sees a problem (in particular in terms of performances) with one of those two approaches. As the first one is far more easy to understand I would prefer it, especially after having reading that:
[Constants and compiler optimization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212237/constants-and-compiler-optimization-in-c)
that seems to allow me to do not fear to write a const_cast and break my performances.

Thank you in advance, cheers,

Manuel

Comment: Nothing personal, but i gave up looking at the Q, the code hurt my eyes too much. :(

Comment: What's wrong with `std::find`? That accepts and returns a non-const iterator.

Comment: std::find does just iterate (linear complexity), in many cases, in particular in the map case underlined above, you can do better. For those cases, you need your own implementation and that's to do such a thing that I need a good design. Of course the problem does not limit to find functions but to any function that does not modify the container but returns iterators and for which you might want that it returns const_iterators while working on const object and iterators otherwise.

Comment: Silly question: Are you sure that `std::find` doesn't actually detect when it's called on a `map` and use the member function? I'm not sure whether that should be the case, but it's possible... If not, I'd probably make some trait class to detect whether something is a container and has a member-find.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. But it is just slightly related to the question because even if it was the case, it would use the find method of the container and then, the problem arises: how to write those methods without duplicating the code for const and non-const contexts.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It would be illegal for `std::find` to use the member function of a `std::map` even if it could. `std::find` must use equality or treat its predicate as an equality operator. See also `std::binary_search`.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, of course. Thanks. Manuel: I guess making a suitable trait-class would be a good start in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might not be very good solutions. Both const overloads and `iterator/const_iterator` are rather clumsy tools to work with.

In the first case, it might be better to let the const version do the work and the non-const version do the casting. That way the compiler would be able to check if your algorithm indeed doesn't modify the container.

Casting a `const_iterator` to `iterator` might be a bit awkward, as it would depend on the implementation details. But you could make a private helper to encapsulate this in a single place.

```
struct A : public Data
{
  iterator find(/*const Key& k */)
  {
    const A *me = this;
    return remove_const_from( me->find(/*k*/) );
  }

  const_iterator find(/*const Key& k */) const{
    return &m; }

    private:
        //could be also static, but in the general case, *this might be needed
        iterator remove_const_from(const_iterator p)
        {
            //in this case just a const_cast
            return const_cast<int*>(p);
        }
};
```

In the second case, you could reduce the verbosity a bit by using template functions and their ability to deduce at least the argument types.

```
struct B : public Data
{
    struct Internal //eventually, could be just a free function?
   {
      template<class Titerator, class Tobj>
      static Titerator find( Tobj& obj/*, const Key& k */ ){
        return &(obj.m); }
    };

  const_iterator find( /*const Key& k */ ) const
  {
    return Internal::find<const_iterator>( *this/*, k*/ );
  }

  iterator find( /*const Key& k */ )
  {
    return Internal::find<iterator>( *this/*, obs*/ );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to share code between const and non-const member functions with the same implementation is to `const_cast` in the non-const one:

```
struct foo
{
    const int* bar() const;
    int* bar() 
    {
        const int* p = static_cast<const foo*>(this)->bar();

        // Perfectly defined since p is not really
        // const in the first place
        return const_cast<int*>(p);
    }
};
```

This works provided the return value of `bar` is a member object of `bar`, which is in fact not const when you call the non-const `bar` (so that `const_cast` is legal).

You cannot write the non-const version and `const_cast` in the const one: this is undefined behavior. You are allowed to remove constness *only if* the object was not const in the first place.

In your example code, since you use bare pointers, you can do:

```
struct A : public Data
{
  const_iterator find(const Key& k) const
  {
      // The real implementation of find is here
  }

  iterator find(const Key& k)
  {
      // Not the other way around !
      const_iterator p = static_cast<const A*>(this)->find(k);
      return const_cast<iterator>(p);
  }
};
```

but as soon as you use more complex iterator types, this won't work: indeed, there is no conversion from standard containers' `const_iterator` to `iterator`, so you're screwed, unless you use plain pointers.

One solution is to factor out the most you can so that you can `const_cast`, and manufacture an iterator at the very end.