# How to use a #define statement in order to set an array of bytes?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, macros

I am programming [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and I would like to use a `#define` statement in order to set an array of bytes to be passed to the [`Ethernet.begin()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin) function. At this time I am using the following code and all works as expected:

```
#define MAC_ARRAY { 0x43, 0xA3, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0xF5, 0xA5 }

void setup() {
  byte mac[] = MAC_ARRAY;

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I have to state `byte mac[] = MAC_ARRAY;` throughout the source code each time I use the `MAC_ARRAY` value. However I would like to avoid stating that (I think also that "on the long way" there could be memory issues since the `mac[]` variable is instantiated) and to pass someway the proper `MAC_ARRAY` directly to the `Ethernet.begin()` function.

Is it possible? If so, how should I change the `#define MAC_ARRAY ...` statement?

Comment: No it's not possible to pass "literal" arrays to functions, unless you have a C++11 compatible compiler/standard library and the functions themselves are coded for that using the [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) class.

Comment: Your code is already simple and correct, there's no need to mess with it

Answer (score 0):

as joachim Pileborg already mentioned, if you have a c++11 compatible compiler it is possible to pass an literal array to a function, and the function (Ethernet.begin) has a `begin(std::initializer_list)` variant.

however, your example is close to a solution. make `mac` *global* (**const** if possible) and remove the define:

```
uint8_t const mac[] = { 0x43, 0xA3, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0xF5, 0xA5 };
   //^^^^^ -> if begin isn't able to handle const, remove the const here.

void setup() {
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

this will instatiate mac only once and reuse it (no memory issue).

there are some possibilities, depending on the code:

1. `Ethernet.begin` is defined with a reference/pointer as parameter. this would mean your are passing just a reference which is ussaly smaller then 6 byte (sizeof(mac)). and mac is just once stored in memory.
2. here mac have to be declared **const**. so the compiler could optimize it and incorporating the value directly into the machines instruction opcodes. therefore you have to compile with optimization-flags on. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212693/1810087)
3. if both are not a case, then it is still ok, because mac is instantinated still once and will be passed by value (copy) over stack memory.

the best is both... `byte const mac` and `begin(byte const*)`, so the compiler would decide the best way to spare memory and time.

---

there is no disadvantage to make it global. a define will result in translated opcode, also maybe global const will (see above case 2) if optimized. but a const will result in one instance also one opcoder (while initializing mac) and the rest in references/aliases to this instance (addressing the value). the behaviour is defined by the implementation of your `Ethernet`.

Comment: You said "this will instatiate mac only once and reuse it (no memory issue)"... what exactly go on memory? those statements consume the same amount of memory (flash, RAM, ...)? and, if any, what are differences at memory level when using `#define` and `const`?

Comment: Why you put `const` inside `/*` `*/`?

Comment: because i don't know if Ethernet.begin() is possible to handle const or not. `const if possible` :)

Comment: *BTW*: The `Ethernet.begin()` function seems do not support the `const` statement: the compiler generates the `invalid conversion from 'const byte*' to 'uint8_t*'` error.

Comment: use uint8_t instead of byte.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38484/discussion-between-itwasntpete-and-backo)

Comment: If I use `uint8_t const ...` I get the `invalid conversion from 'const uint8_t*' to 'uint8_t*'` error.