# How to tell c++ compiler that the object is not changed elsewhere to reach better optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, constants, volatile

I would like to optimize some C++ code. Let have a simplified example:

```
int DoSomeStuff(const char* data)
{

  while(data != NULL)
  {
    //compute something and use optimization as much as possible
  }
  return result;
}
```

I know that `*data` is not changed elsewhere. I mean it's not changed in any other thread, but the compiler cannot know. Is there some way to tell the compiler that data on the pointer are not changed for the entire lifetime of the scope?

UPDATE:

```
int DoSomeStuff(const volatile char* data)
{

  while(data != NULL)
  {
    //compiler should assume that the data are changed elsewhere
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You already do that by making it const.

Comment: Unless `data` is a pointer to `(const) volatile char *`, the compiler may already assume that the pointed-to data isn't changed by another thread.

Comment: @Samuel No, `const` doesn't have that meaning. `const` just means read-only, but doesn't tell the compiler the pointed-to memory isn't modified in other ways. For example, `int f(const int *a, int *b) { int c = *a; ++*b; return c - *a; }` must take into account that `a` and `b` may point to the same object. (But modifications by another thread are special, the compiler may assume that that doesn't happen regardless of `const`.)

Comment: I don't think the compiler *protects* you from changes from any other thread at all.

Comment: @hvd: If variable `a` in your example is pointing to a read-only memory section (e.g., RO-data), then your code will cause a memory-access violation during runtime. Therefore, in OP's example, I believe that for `const char* data`, the compiler has to assume that `data` is possibly pointing to a read-only memory section. Under this assumption, the compiler may then perform the relevant optimization.

Comment: hvd: So the compiler already assumes, that the data are not changed by other thread (because of absense of the volatile keyword) and the optimization are already performed? Am I right.

Comment: related : [Constants and compiler optimization in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212237/constants-and-compiler-optimization-in-c)

Comment: @qub1n: No ... at least probably no. There is probably no way (let global optimization out of the equation and some easy scope examples) that the compiler/optimizer can be sure that no other piece of code holds a non-const reference on your data.

Comment: @barakmanos The pointer *may* point to read-only memory. It may also point to writeable memory. The compiler has to take both possibilities into account.

Comment: @qub1n Yes, sort of. Dominik Selzer rightly pointed out that the compiler cannot tell in the general case that the data won't be changed *by functions called from the same thread*. It can and generally does assume that *if no functions are called*, the data won't be changed by another thread.

Comment: @qub1n Your update doesn't apply here: that quote applies to objects *defined* with `const`. It doesn't apply to the objects pointed-to by `const`-qualified pointers, because `const`-qualified pointers may point to objects defined with or without `const`.

Comment: I have deleted the incorrect quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1) Will the compiler optimize if the variable is **const** ?

According to the standard (7.1.6.1):

```
A pointer or reference to a cv-qualified type need not actually point or refer
to a cv-qualified object, but it is treated as if it does
```

So I understand it as: the compiler will optimize all access to a **const** qualified variable **as if** it really was a const data and could not be modified by a path to a non const variable.

#### 2) Will the compiler not optimize to protect inter-thread access ?

According to the standard (1.10):

```
The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting
actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither
happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.
```

A *conflicting action* is defined as:

```
Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location
(1.7) and the other one accesses or modifies the same memory location.
```

The *happens-before* relationship is complex but as I understand it, unless you explicitly used atomic operations (or mutexes) in your code, accessing the same variable from two threads (one writing, another one reading/writing) is undefined behavior. This case being **undefined behavior** I don't think the compiler will protect you, and it is free to optimize.

#### 3) Volatile ?

Volatile is designed to prevent optimization (7.1.6.1):

```
volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization
involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means
undetectable by an implementation
```

Think about a memory mapped I/O register (like a special input port). Even though you cannot write it (because your hardware implementation is read-only), you cannot optimiza your read accesses (because they will return a different byte each time). This special I/O port may be a temperature sensor for instance.

Comment: Nice answer. I still don't understand why MSVC has __restrict  keyword if compiler threat const pointer as it is const.

Comment: @qub1n In the example use of **__restrict**, the pointers are not pointing to const data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ft82fed.aspx. So I think this is yet another case :)

Comment: In the example code the pointers are const - not pointing to const data, that would be char* const - maybe that would helper the compiler out more

Comment: @paulm I was speaking about the MSDN example, not yours.

Comment: "So I understand it as: the compiler will optimize all access to a const qualified variable as if it really was a const data and could not be modified by a path to a non const variable." -- Absolutely not. I already gave an example of a perfectly valid function in my comments on the question that would break if your interpretation were correct. "it is treated as if it does" means for purposes of static typing etc. The text in the standard *immediately* following your quote already clears this up.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is already allowed to assume `*data` is not modified by another thread. Modifying data in one thread and accessing it in another thread without proper synchronisation is *Undefined Behaviour*. The compiler is totally free to do anything at all with a program that contains undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're saying is that its not *aliased* anywhere else.

In MSVC you can do:

```
int DoSomeStuff(const char* __restrict  data)
{

  while(data != NULL)
  {
    //compute something and use optimization as much as possible
  }
  return result;
}
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ft82fed.aspx

Comment: The MSDN says: `The __restrict keyword indicates that a symbol is not aliased in the **current scope**`. But you only have one argument to your function, how could it be aliased in the current scope ?

Comment: const char* bar = data;